# The word for a "magazine containing solely ads"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for a **magazine that contains only advertisements**?

Plus, can you say *advertising*, or *advertisement magazine*?

edit: I don't mean a leaflet (a single sheet of paper)

Comment: I'd generally call this a "flier".

Comment: I call those things **circulars**. They come through my door from local furniture shops, garden centres etc. They sometimes contain articles – like home tips intended to get you to buy their products.

Comment: In the south of the USA, Greensheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen plenty of these called ***shoppers***. The word often shows up in the name of the newspaper or magazine. They may contain nominal 'news' items but their focus is advertising. Here's one example, [***The Monadnock Shopper News***](http://www.shoppernews.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Catalogue is the term I would use. The famous example is the Sears Catalogue. This corresponds to definition 4 in this [Wiktionary entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/catalogue#English).

If you were to say advertisement magazine, I would find this strange but would probably understand what you mean with a bit of thinking.